# Android activity navigation issue

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a problem with navigating through activities. I am navigating from HomeActivity to Activity A. When I move from Home to Activity A, I finish the HomeActivity and starts another activity Activity B. When I start Activity B, I am not finishing Activity A. So when I finish Activity B normally it should go to Activity A. But In my case it is not working. When I call finish() in Activity B, both Activity B and Activity A is getting finished.

Can anybody suggest a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you supply some code and details of any errors you may have encountered please.

Comment: finish the HomeActivity and start Activity B from the onCreate of Activity A, or at least start Activity B from the onCreate of activity A to avoid having globals and potential leaks

Comment: Don't call `finish()` when you are simply starting another activity, the system takes care of that. Calling `finish()` is not a normal behavior for an activity.